# UserControl for cross-platform Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, user-controls, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I have been looking for a long time now but still haven't found a way to create WPF like UserControls for cross-platform Xamarin Forms. Can this even be done? I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a XAML example. Just to add you can have any base visual element. E.g. a Grid, StackLayout, Image etc.

```
 <Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.Control.UserControl">

 </Grid>
```

Here is the code behind

```
namespace Mobile.Control
{
    public partial class UserControl : Grid
    {
        public UserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

    }
}
```

To use it, go to your page and implement the namespace

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Mobile.Control;assembly=Mobile"
          x:Class="Mobile.View.MyPage">
```

And then in the page

```
<control:UserControl />
```

Comment: what is the the Header function there?

Comment: @batmaci - a copy and paste error. I have updated the code.

Comment: I get an error stating InitializeComponent doesn't exist in the current context.  Is that a proper call for a class that derives from Grid?

Comment: @bigwavesoftware - yes if you have XAML you need to call InitializeComponent, because it calls LoadXaml. Sometimes you will get an intellisense error but your build should still succeed. Make sure you use the latest version of Xamarin Forms to ensure you don't get the intellisense error.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to follow up, I found by right clicking the XAML and "Run Custom Tool", it cleared up the issue and the Intellisense worked as well.

Comment: I tried this and I get 'Could not load file or assembly "<Namespace Name>" or one of its dependencies. Note: I'm using shared project.

Comment: @PLOW that is because a Shared Project isn't its own assembly and each project has its own assembly name. Either change each of your traditional xamarin projects assembly names to the same, or try removing the Assembly attribute but leave the namespace from the xmlns:control

Comment: Changing the assembly name on iOS to match the assemble name did not work or removing the assembly attribute. It gave me a Xaml parse exemption error

Comment: your solution is beautiful. However I wish that you showed how to bind the usercontrol elements to the parent container page.

Comment: @stackunderflow - I blogged about how to do that here: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/ If you want to bind a property in the user control to the page that it is placed in, that is easy, just bind it as normal. The UserControl takes on the BindingContext of the page it is placed in. You only need to do something special if you want to bind it to a property in the UserControl itself.