# How to reuse the same view in Xamarin? XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I got this code that I need to re-use on more or less all my pages, but I'm getting kinda tired of changing one page and having to do the same thing in 10 or more places, are there any better way to do this?

Using Xamarin.Forms. Maybe it is possible to do this with a custom controller or some other way with markup extension to inside a stacklayout do a x:static reference to it?

```
   <!--#region BOTTOM Navigation Bar-->

        <!-- Theme Colored bar-->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding="0,0,0,0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" >
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Menu bar -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding="0,3,0,3" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ThemeBkColorBottomBar}" >

            <!-- Left -->
            <StackLayout Padding="15,0,0,0" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal"  >

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="2">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToCheckUpdates}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Image Source="updates.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label Text="Updates" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />

                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
            <!-- Center -->
            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0,0,0,0" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="2" >
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToCatalog}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Image Source="catalogues.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="Catalog" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="2">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToPresentation}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Image Source="display.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="Presentations" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="2">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToScan}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Image Source="scan.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="Scanner" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="2">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToSearch}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Image Source="Search.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="Search" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Right -->
            <StackLayout Padding="0,0,15,0" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="2">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CmdGoToLoginLogout}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image Source="logout.png" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" >
                    </Image>
                    <Label Text="Settings" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource BottomMenuBtnText}" />
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        <!--#endregion-->
```

Comment: You can create your own user control for those views and just use it on your pages. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701449/usercontrol-for-cross-platform-xamarin-forms) a pretty good example

Comment: Sweet! That is absolutely what I'm looking for, if I wanted to example not include one of the stacklayout  "image-buttons", how would I do that? For example, in the login view or maybe instead of a customer using the app it's an admin which should have an extra button visible for just him?

Comment: You could add a [bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) that shows and hides the button or even adds or removes views to your control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a CustomView and then include that in your Pages.

In order to Achieve that, you create a a YourCustomView.xaml,

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourProject.YourCustomView">

</ContentView>
```

And, in your Page.xaml you include it

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:YourProject;assembly=YourProject"
             x:Class="YourProject.YourPage">
    <views:YourCustomView/> 
</ContentPage>
```

The next step is about Binding the properties that you need, for that, you need to create BindableProperties in your CustomView. You can reuse this in all pages that you want.

Comment: This is not reusing, it inherently creates new ui objects foreach page using it. Will be very slow

Comment: @user1034912, it seems that you misunderstood the concept of OOP and reusing objects, methods or properties. For reusing objects or properties from other classes or pages, we need to create multiple instances of that entity. What you think of is sharing objects or properties, for that we use static. Please note that reusing objects will always need instances for accessing each time. If we don't want to consider using objects, we will need to declare them static.

Comment: @user1034912, You want to reuse a control that's defined earlier. Hence, whenever we will need that control, we will duplicate it by creating a new instance of it. We can't just render a control by copying it from where it is defined or rendered.