# Adding a Frame into a grid from a c# Function that iterates through my data source (Observable collection)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Simply - my binding data will dictate what col / row to put it in..

I dont want to write multiple frame layout code into XAML - but rather write the fame once in page level or app level resource, then generate an  instance of this - populate it - and put into the grid specified in the binding.

The bit where it says TASK 1  is the repeating element frame.

```
<Grid Margin="0" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="2" RowSpacing="2" IsVisible="true">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <!-- TASK 1-->
                <Frame CornerRadius="5"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"   
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"    
                    HasShadow="True" Padding="0">

                    <Grid Margin="0" Padding="10" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <Image Source="tbt_logo.png"                     
                            WidthRequest="64" HeightRequest="64"
                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            />

                        <Label Text="16" 
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           FontSize="42"
                           Margin="0,0,0,-20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Start" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        />

                        <Label Text="Files sent" 
                           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           FontSize="Small"  
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Start"                        
                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                         />

                        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Margin="0,10,0,-10"></BoxView>

                        <Label Text="View Info" 
                           Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           Margin="0,0"
                           FontSize="Small" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="End"                        
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           />
                        <Image Source="tbt_logo.png"                     
                            WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"                          
                               VerticalOptions="End" 
                            Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                            />
                    </Grid>

                </Frame>


                <!-- TASK 2 -->
                <Frame CornerRadius="5"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"    
                    HasShadow="True" Padding="0">

                    <Grid Margin="0" Padding="10" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <Image Source="tbt_logo.png"                     
                            WidthRequest="64" HeightRequest="64"
                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            />

                        <Label Text="16" 
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           FontSize="42"
                           Margin="0,0,0,-20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Start" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        />

                        <Label Text="Files sent" 
                           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           FontSize="Small"  
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Start"                        
                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                         />

                        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Margin="0,10,0,-10"></BoxView>

                        <Label Text="View Info" 
                           Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
                           TextColor="Green"
                           Margin="0,0"
                           FontSize="Small" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="End"                        
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           />
                        <Image Source="tbt_logo.png"                     
                            WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"                          
                               VerticalOptions="End" 
                            Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                            />
                    </Grid>

                </Frame>

            </Grid>
   </grid>
```

Comment: Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should create a frame template and simply reference it in your view. Label and Image source properties can be bindable properties. Create a contentview with your frame xaml in another file and reference it twice for each task in your current file.

Comment: ahh ok - so like im making any other XAML page, then in my codebehind. on the page I want to reference it in. just reference from there and set the binding?

Comment: Pretty much, you can reference the template from xaml or code behind both. Read this, it should be a good reference for your case: https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: thanks, I will give that a go - and if it helps. somehow mark your response as the answer :)

Comment: ive been googling the hell out if it, but only recently started Xamarin last week (I do VB.net  aspx etc etc) but knowing what to exactly search, was my sticking point.

Comment: No problem. Also, worth noting that you can create a custom control(template) using both code behind and xaml and reference it as well. You should, however, get comfortable with xaml before completely coding in c#. Another answer from SO that may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306962/how-to-reuse-the-same-view-in-xamarin-xaml

Comment: Thanks again :)  I have an error happening in that I cant convert Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject Project.Views.FrameTemplate (what I called the new  control im doing)

iam using a Master/Detail layout.. so MVVM   - i just looked above, and It appears I neglected to mention that

Comment: I apparently need 20 rep points to do that :)

Comment: If your issue is solved, nevermind that! If you still need help, ping me.

Comment: emailed you - from my personal account - let me know you got it :)

Comment: This has been answered perfectly by @SparshaBhattarai  THANK YOU ALL

Comment: @DogsoldierUK If have solved , you can share solution in answer , this will be helpful for others. :)

Comment: Hello JuniorJiang-MSFT, the answer was provided by @SparshaBhattarai.   I will provide his answer in the Answer my own question bit of this (i dont use StackOverflow much) lol  :)

Comment: @DogsoldierUK Great , you are welcome in StackOverFlow :)

Answer (score 0):

So, from the advisement of Sparsha Bhattarai, I created the frame template that i want to reuse.

**FrameTemplate.Xaml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MMPTaskStats.Views.FrameTemplate">

    <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame CornerRadius="5" x:Name="task_color"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"   
                BackgroundColor="White"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"    
                HasShadow="True" Padding="0">

            <Grid Margin="0" Padding="10" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Text="/ of 12" 
                   x:Name="task_locale"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="Small"  
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start"                        
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" />

                <Image x:Name="task_icon"
                   Source="tbt_logo.png"      
                   HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="50"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Label Text="16" 
                   x:Name="task_headline"                      
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="27"
                   Margin="0,0,0,-20"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />

                <Label Text="/ of 12" 
                   x:Name="task_subline"
                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="Small"  
                   VerticalTextAlignment="End"                        
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />

                <Label Text="Files sent" 
                   x:Name="task_status"
                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="Small"  
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start"                        
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />

                <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,1,0,-1"></BoxView>

                <Label Text="View Info" 
                       Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       TextColor="White"
                       Margin="0,0"                       
                       FontSize="Small" 
                       VerticalTextAlignment="End"                        
                       VerticalOptions="End"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       />
                <Image Source="tbt_logo.png"                     
                        WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16"
                           HorizontalOptions="End"                          
                           VerticalOptions="End" 
                        Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
                        />
            </Grid>

        </Frame>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Then the codeBehind for it looked like this.

```
namespace Project.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FrameTemplate : ContentView
    {
        public FrameTemplate(string locale,string headline, string subHeadline, string icon, Color bgcolor, string status) : this()
        {
            //Here i have initialized the view from constructor, but you can simply set the binding of the view and set the properties. Do look into it. You can just as easily use the view in xaml but it will require a parameterless constructor. So, binding is important.            
            task_locale.Text = locale;
            task_headline.Text = headline;
            task_subline.Text = subHeadline;
            task_icon.Source = icon;
            task_color.BackgroundColor = bgcolor;
            task_status.Text = status;
        }


        public FrameTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

    }

}
```

THEN, in the page / view I want this to appear

```
var frame = new FrameTemplate("UK TP Stats", "999999", "/ of 999999", "tick.png", Color.Green, "Sent");
            Grid.SetColumn(frame, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(frame, 0);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(frame);
```

This worked for me, which was great, I can now replicate this to do similar layouts etc as needed.

My Xamarin.Forms project is a Master/Detail template too, just in case anybody wanted to know :)